# Function of verb “to let someone do something”

Tags: grammar

Is there a difference grammatically between sentences like “I allowed him to play” and ones like “I let him play”?

“I allowed him to play” is clearly just “[subject] [verb] [direct object] [infinitive],” but in the second sentence, is “play” still considered an infinitive phrase, or is there something else going on?

Comment: Some verbs like _let_ (or sense verbs like _see, watch, hear,_ and _feel_) can take infinitive object clauses ("complements") without a _to_; it's a special exception for those verbs only. All others, like _want_ or _allow_, need a _to_ marking their infinitive complements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *I allowed him* [*to play*].
>
> [2] *I let him* [*play*].

The bracketed elements are both infinitival clauses.

The grammar is the same in both examples, as is the meaning. The only difference is that "allow" requires a *to*-infinitival complement, while "let" requires a bare infinitival complement.

"Allow" and "let" are catenative verbs and the subordinate clauses "to play" / "play" are not objects but catenative complements.

Syntactically, "him" is direct object of "allow" and "let", and the semantic (understood) subject of the infinitival clauses.

"Him" is called a 'raised object' since the verb that "him" relates to syntactically is higher in the constituent structure than the one it relates to semantically.