# Is "Let" Part of a Verb Phrase?

Tags: grammar

- *Simply let a semicolon take the place of a conjunction with a comma.*

Is "let" and the infinitive "(to) take" considered a verb phrase, or is "let" the lone verb in the sentence? Also, what word is the infinitive phrase "to take the place of a conjunction with a comma" modifying?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the first paragraph of your question supposed to be an example sentence? (If so, put a "> " before it in your question so that it shows up as a block quote.)

Comment: And you need to tell us what definition of "verb phrase" you're using.

Comment: let to take is not a verb phrase. "let x take the place" is one.

Comment: Compare https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539504/function-of-verb-to-let-someone-do-something https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17791/is-this-grammatical-construction-an-imperative-for-the-third-person

Answer (score 2):

> *Simply let a semicolon* [*take the place of a conjunction with a comma*].

This is an imperative clause in a catenative construction where "let" is the catenative verb and the bracketed subordinate clause as its catenative complement.

The whole sequence is a clause consisting of a verb phrase, and likewise the subordinate clause. The intervening NP, "a semicolon", is the object of "let" and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.

The subject of the matrix clause is omitted (as is usual in imperative clauses), but understood as "you".

Comment: @cookie234  Incidentally, I've glossed over the fact that the sentence doesn't make any sense. What purpose does the PP "with a comma" serve?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

*Let him go to town* -> (S (VP let (NP him) (VP go (ADVP to town))))

Your example is over-complex. The additional words are not significant

*Simply let a semicolon take the place of a conjunction with a comma.*

1. In “*take the place*” **take** is a light verb and the meaning is “*replace*”
2. “*with a comma*” is not needed

-> *Let a semicolon replace a conjunction*-> (S (VP Let (NP a semicolon) (VP replace (NP a conjunction))))

Comment: where is the verb phrase? Let x replace where let is an imperative.

Comment: @Lambie You ask "where is the verb phrase?" - "within the brackets and preceded by "VP"

Comment: I don't see "let" as a verb phrase.

Comment: @Lambie You are not reading the brackets. *Let a semicolon replace a conjunction* and *replace a conjunction* are VPs.